# If statment trouble

Tags: bash, shell-script

I've written the following script:

```
#!/bin/bash

SINGLE=`cut -c 7-13 Data.txt`

cd ../FASTA_SEC_EDITED/

for i in ${SINGLE}; do
    if [[ -r "${i}_Forward_Trimmed.fa" && -r ../REVERSE_COMP/"${i}_Reverse_RevComp.fa"]]
    then
        cp ${i}_Forward_Trimmed.fa ../Aling/Input_Muscle/${i}_Input.fa >> ../REVERSE_COMP/${i}_Reverse_RevComp.fa
        usr/bin/muscle3.8.31_i86linux64 -in ../Aling/Input_Muscle/${i}_Input.fa -out ../Align/${i}_CONSENSUS.fa

    else
        echo "Does not exist"
    fi
done
```

But but something seems to be wrong with the if statement.. Bash returns the following error:

```
muscle_test.sh: line 8: syntax error in conditional expression
muscle_test.sh: line 9: syntax error near `then'
muscle_test.sh: line 9: `   then'
```

I've been gooling about writing an AND operator in of but it seems to be ok, I'm not sure what's wrong there. Any idea?

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you forgot the space before closing brace. It should be so

```
if [[ -r "${i}_Forward_Trimmed.fa" && -r ../REVERSE_COMP/"${i}_Reverse_RevComp.fa" ]]
```

Comment: @Neuls if this answer solved your question, please [accept it](http://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) by clicking on the checkmark to the left. That's the way thanks are expressed on Stack Exchange sites and that will mark the question as answered.